# Issue w/ Symbol Substitution in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbols, substitution

I want to define a symbol and use it within a function. For example, with IDnumbers defined as a list of numbers:

```
ParallelMap[{#1, Name[#1], Age[#1]} &, IDnumbers]
```

With `userlist={#1, Name[#1], Age[#1]}` becomes:

```
ParallelMap[userlist &, IDnumbers]
```

It works just fine with the list itself in the code, but not with the symbol. The same thing happens with a list of strings vs. a symbol assigned to a list of strings. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `f[#]&` is shorthand for `Function[f[#]]` you should always complete your anonymous function with a trailing `&` to get a working function.
In your example:

```
userlist={#1, Name[#1], Age[#1]}&
ParallelMap[userlist, IDnumbers]
```

**More thorough explanation:**

By just using something like `f[#]` you get (in `FullForm[]`)

```
In[15]            := f[#] // FullForm
Out[15]//FullForm  = f[Slot[1]]
```

whereas this gets transformed to a Function by the trailing `&` operator:

```
In[16]            := f[#]& // FullForm
Out[16]//FullForm  = Function[f[Slot[1]]]
```

If you do this in two steps, `&` doesn't evaluate the intermediate variable `expr`:

```
In[25]:= expr = f[#]//FullForm
In[26]:= expr &
Out[25]//FullForm = f[Slot[1]]
Out[26]           = expr &
```

You can force the evaluation of `expr` before it gets wrapped in the `Function[]` by using `Evaluate[]`:

```
In[27]:= expr=f[#]//FullForm
In[28]:= Evaluate[expr]&
Out[27]//FullForm = f[Slot[1]]
Out[28]           = f[Slot[1]]&
```

Another way is to supply the `Function[]` wrapper yourself:

```
userlist={#1, Name[#1], Age[#1]}
ParallelMap[Function[userlist], IDnumbers]
```

Personally, i would consider this bad coding style. Just get used to always finishing an anonymous function with a trailing `&` like you would supply a closing paranthesis `)` to a corresponding opening one `(`.

**Edit**
Ok, in your case of a dynamically generated anonymous function i can see why you couldn't supply the `&` directly. Just wrap the expression with the `Slot[]`s in a `Function[]` instead.

Comment: How do I add an ampersand outside the list brackets? Here's the code that defines userlist, where hd is something like `{"ID", "Name", "Age"}`:

`lll = StringReplace[ToString@hd, "," -> "@#,"];
llo = StringReplace[ToString@lll, "ID@" -> ""];
llj = StringDrop[llo, 1];
llm = StringReplacePart[llj, "@#", -1];
llx = StringSplit[llm, ","];
llk = StringReplace[llx, " " -> ""];
userlist = ToExpression@llk`

Sorry for the bad formatting!

Comment: use `userlist = Function@ToExpression@llk` for the last step.

Comment: When I wrap `userlist` in `Function[]` (`ParallelMap[Function[userlist]...`) the elements of `userlist` are not evaluated. They're separated out into their respective rows and columns correctly, but they still read `Age[#1]` for example...?